# Passing textView to label -iphone

Tags: objective-c

I have a `viewController` with a `textView` and a secondviewController with a `label` I'm trying to pass on the text in the textView to the label

First

```
.m

textView= [[UITextView alloc] initwithFrame...
```

//change view and send textview to label

```
-(void) gotoSecond:(id) sender{
Second *sec = [[Second alloc]initWithNibName: @"Second" bundle:nil];
[sec.note setText:textView.text]
[self presentViewController:sec animated: YES completion:NULL]; 

}

Second .h
```

//attached on nib

```
@propery (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *note;
```

Comment: So what happens? Is it giving an error? Or is the text not set? Is sec.note `! nil`, when you try setting the text?

Comment: Sounds like a broken binding or some similar issue. Except you are not using XIB but initializing the `UILabel` programmatically. Then you would have to see that you initialize it at an early point.

Comment: okay so I can't use xib with the label? And it's not returning an error, just label text isn't being set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

In viewController.m

```
-(void) gotoSecond{
secondViewController *sec = [[secondViewController alloc]initWithNibName: @"Second" bundle:nil];
[sec.passedText setText:textView.text]
[self presentViewController:sec animated: YES completion:NULL]; 

}
```

In secondViewController.h

```
@property(nonatomic, strong)NSString *passedText;
```

In secondViewController.m

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
   self.note.text = passedText;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! worked with the slight edit

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
-(void) gotoSecond:(id) sender{
    Second *sec = [[Second alloc]initWithNibName: @"Second" bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:sec animated: YES completion:^(){
         [sec.note setText:textView.text];
    }]; 
}
```